# Security issuse about header ('location: some_page.php')

Tags: php

I have a question about `header('location: ----.php')`. Is it safe for an ADMIN to use this function to restrict USER access for some pages? For example if a user is not an ADMIN can I use this function to prevent the user from seeing some pages? Is this a good way to secure some pages from unauthorized access? If not can someone give me a suggestion for secure restriction?

For example I'm using this for restriction:

```php
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'"); 
$row_12 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
$admin = $row_12['admin_id'];
$ruka = $row_12['rukovoditelj'];


if($row_12['admin_id'] > 1)
{
    header('Location: dosjei.php');
}
```

Comment: The redirect occurs at the discretion of the user agent / browser. So unless you also prevent further script execution `exit(header("Location: ..."));` it's just an UI effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's safe assuming you stop the execution of the script after (with the exit; order for instance).

```
header("Location: dosjei.php");
exit;
```

Of course you need to do the verification at the beginning of the script before to write on the page some data you need to hide to unauthorized users.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe. But only if you exit afterwards. This way, even if the user didn't respect the `Location` header, he still won't be able to see anything. Something along the lines of:

```
if ($row_12['admin_id'] < 1) {
    header("Location: dosjei.php");
    die();
}

display_content_for_authorized_users(); //Would never be reached if $unauthorized is true.
```

Comment: Is there a difference between ending with die(); or exit; ? I meen from security point.

Comment: There isn't. One is an alias for the other. They are the same.

Comment: @Reddwarf: I urge you to accept Olivier's answer. His answer is as much correct as mine, and he answered before I did.

Comment: @Reddwarf: You can't :) But his answer came first, so it is much fairer if you accepted his answer, and not mine.

Comment: I apologize :) you are right and I'm grateful for reply's  ;)